# Regex to match multiple strings with words between them

Tags: regex, string, match

I want to match several categories as seen below.

```
Author: name
Category: CatA and CatB
Title: title
```

Wanted result: 'CatA CatB'

First I matched the whole line, then everything after 'Category:'
But to reduce data cleaning afterwards Id like to omit as much as possible.

Right now I'm using `(?!:Kategori:)\s(\w+\S)`
Giving me 'CatA and CatB'

Specifics:

- Both categories can be multiple words, but no other words than **and** will separate them.
- Categories start with a Capital letter.
- There can be one or two categories.

example:

```
Category: Boat and Small boat
```

wanted result:
Boat Small boat

Comment: Which language? I'm assuming it's PCRE since `\K` works and that's most common engine supporting the token

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think its 'JavaScript'. Have been trying a couple of different ways to do this. And as you can tell I'm not really proficient in regex yet :)

Comment: It's not JavaScript unless it's an imported library as it doesn't support `\K` natively. What language are you writing the regex in?

Comment: Put no weight on my faulty regex. I'm using a regex-tool to test things faster. Language is JavaScript.

Comment: Ok no problem, your regex won't work right now due to `\K` token being invalid in JavaScript - that's a reset token, but JavaScript will see it as the literal `K` character.

Comment: Confirmed, not working. Thanks for pointing that out! Do you have any ideas how to solve this matching with JavaScript regex?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't use regex for this. You can use the following code to accomplish what you need. The nice thing is you can also have multiple `Category:`  instances and it'll return you multiple arrays (one for each).

```js
s = `Author: name
Category: CatA and CatB
Title: title`
f = "Category: "

x = s.split('\n').filter(function(e){return e.startsWith(f)})
x.forEach(function(e,i){x[i] = e.replace(f,"").split(' and ')})
console.log(x)
```

Sample with multiple `Category:`  instances below:

```js
s = `Author: name
Category: CatA and CatB
Title: title
Author: name
Category: Boat and Small boat
Title: title`
f = "Category: "

x = s.split('\n').filter(function(e){return e.startsWith(f)})
x.forEach(function(e,i){x[i] = e.replace(f,"").split(' and ')})
console.log(x)
```

How it works:

1. Split on newline chars
2. Then filter out any rows that don't start with var string `f` (`Category:` )
3. Loop over results
4. Replace `f` var string in each result (leaves us with `CatA and CatB`)
5. Split that result on `and` to get every category as per OP's details